# AngularJs TypeError: $scope.todos.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, typeerror

I am trying to use the $http.get method to add a todo from my controller to my DB. But I am getting the error "TypeError: $scope.todos.push is not a function". I have looked at many similar questions to my own, and tried to implement the suggestions, with no success. The issue is in the  $scope.createTodo function of the TodoController.

**todo.controller.js**

```
 angular.module('app')

   .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', 'Todos', function TodoController($scope, Todos) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    console.log("in the TodoController");
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    Todos.get()
    .then(function (data){
        $scope.todos = data;
    }).then(function (error){

    });

    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        if(!$scope.todoForm.$valid) {
            return;
        }
        Todos.create($scope.formData)
        .then(function (data){
             $scope.formData = {};
             $scope.todos.push(data);
        }).then(function (error){

        });
    };
```

**todo.service.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('Todos', ['$http', function($http) {

return {
    get: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/todos');

    },

    create: function(todoData) {
        return $http.get('/api/todos', todoData).then(function (success){

        },function (error){

        });

    },

    delete: function(id) {
        return $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id);
    },

    update: function(todoData) {
        return $http.put('/api/todos/' + todoData.id, todoData);
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: put a breakpoint in `Todos.get().then(function (data){ ... })` and check what exactly you are assigning to `$scope.todos`. My guess it is **not** an array.

Comment: The problem is your initial assignment of `todos` - you should log the `data` variable in your `.then` response - it's not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not declare $scope.todos so its return undefined and does not have push function, I think you have to declare your table before:

```
angular.module('app')

   .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', 'Todos', function TodoController($scope, Todos) {
    $scope.todos = [];
    $scope.formData = {};
    console.log("in the TodoController");
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    Todos.get()
    .then(function (data){
        $scope.todos = [data];
    }).then(function (error){

    });

    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        if(!$scope.todoForm.$valid) {
            return;
        }
        Todos.create($scope.formData)
        .then(function (data){
             $scope.formData = {};
             $scope.todos.push(data);
        }).then(function (error){

        });
    };
```

Comment: I added the line  $scope.todos = []; to my controller, but still not working. Thanks

Comment: you still have TypeError: $scope.todos.push is not a function

Answer (score 1):

To get rid from this kind of issue.

I simply first check not `'undefined'` to perform any operation like push or length

```
if($scope.todos != undefined){
    //to do here
} else {
    console.log("$scope.todos is undefined");
}

//or

if($scope.todos !== 'undefined'){
    //to do here
}
```

May help someone suffering with this tiny issue.

Answer (score 0):

Push works on array only, convert that model to an array your problem will be solved.